# how to perform a search for words in one file against another file and display the first matching word in a line

Tags: awk, grep

I have an annoying problem. I have two files.

```
$ cat file1
Sam
Tom
```

```
$ cat file2
I am Sam. Sam I am.
Tom
I am Tom. Tom I am.
```

File 1 is a word list file whereas file2 is a  file containing varying number of columns. I want to perform a search using file 1 against file2, display all possible the first matching word that appear in each line of file2. Thus the result needs to be the following:

```
Sam (line 1 match)
Tom (line 2 match)
Tom (line 3 match)
```

If the f2 is the following,

```
I am Sam. Sam I am.
Tom
I am Tom. Tom I am.
I am Tom. Sam I am.
I am Sam. Tom I am.
I am Sammy.
```

It needs to display the following:

```
Sam (1st line match)
Tom (2nd line match)
Tom (3rd line match)
Tom (4th line match)
Sam (4th line match)
Sam (5th line match)
Tom (5th line match)
Sam (6th line match)
```

I think I need an awk solution since the command "grep -f file1 file2" won't work.

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have in order to solve your own problem and let us know then.

Comment: I tried awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' file1 file2

Comment: You mean the line "I am Tom. Tom I am."?  Just first matching word "Tom".  Since "Tom" appears in line 2 and line3, the first matching word needs to be displayed.

Comment: It is also not clear if you want to match a full column or a substring is also enough

Comment: Substring.  You are right.  I shouldn't have used the expression non-greedy.

Comment: Actually that doesn't matter to me. It needs to match the first instance in a line. If the word occurs more than once, then ignore the rest and display the first matching word. All the solutions work, although it may not work for a large file size.

Comment: Yes, Ed.  I realize that they do different things. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc" }
NR==FNR { res[$0]; next }
{
    delete found
    for ( re in res ) {
        if ( !(re in found) ) {
            if ( match($0,re) ) {
                found[re] = RSTART
            }
        }
    }
    for ( re in found ) {
        printf "%s (line #%d match)\n", re, FNR
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
Sam (line #1 match)
Tom (line #2 match)
Tom (line #3 match)
Tom (line #4 match)
Sam (line #4 match)
Sam (line #5 match)
Tom (line #5 match)
Sam (line #6 match)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I appreciate it. It's a perfect solution for me since file1 can have more than one word.

Comment: You're welcome. Just be aware I'm going unanchored partial matching with regexps. If you wanted full line or full word or start-of-word or any other kind of matching on parts of strings or if you wanted to do string rather than regexp matching then it'd be a different solution. All I can say about this one is it works with your posted input but so would many other variants.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want first match from each line:

```
$ cat f1
Sam
Tom
$ cat f2
I am Sam. Sam I am.
Tom
I am Tom. Tom I am.
I am Tom. Sam I am.
I am Sam. Tom I am.

$ grep -Fnof f1 f2 | sort -t: -u -k1,1n
1:Sam
2:Tom
3:Tom
4:Tom
5:Sam
```

- `-n` option to display line number which is later used to remove duplicates
- `-F` option to match search terms literally and not as regex
- `-o` to display only matching terms
- pipe the output to `cut -d: --complement -f1` to remove first column of line numbers

Comment: I tried your solution and I found out that this is not exactly what I needed. I need the output like this:

Sam
Tom
Tom
Tom
Sam
Tom

The last line "I am Sam. Tom I am." has bot Sam and Tom. So it needs to display both.

Comment: @EungiKim, please do wrap your expected output in code tags and better to post it in your post NOT in comments(so all will be aware of it) and let us know then.

Comment: yes. I am trying. Now I realize the 4th line has Tom and Sam as well.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"[. ]" 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in a){print $i;next}}}'  Input_file1   Input_file2
```

Comment: this will not work for something like `I am Tom. Tomy I am.` because you are splitting line by whitespace and `Tom.` wouldn't match

Comment: @Sundeep, Thank you for letting know added `-F"[. ]" ` as per shown samples in my solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems grep could be made to work

```
grep -nof f1 f2 | sort -u
1:Sam
2:Tom
3:Tom
4:Sam
4:Tom
5:Sam
5:Tom
6:Sam
```

Comment: This is a very elegant, simple solution. Thank you.