# awk to join on first column of two files that consist of multiple columns

Tags: unix, join, awk, inner-join

I have two files: a.txt and b.txt.

cat a.txt
a1 c1
a1 c2
a2 c1
a2 c2

cat b.txt
a1 d1
a2 d1
a2 d2
a3 d2

Using awk, I need to join by the first column. The output needs to be like the output that would be generated the join command.

join <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
a1 c1 d1
a1 c2 d1
a2 c1 d1
a2 c1 d2
a2 c2 d1
a2 c2 d2

I have tried the following:
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in A){print $1, A[$1], $2; next}' a.txt b.txt

However, it doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting or just look at other questions (including [your own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55676816/1745001)) for how to format your sample input, output, and code.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use `join`, but this can be an `awk` solution.

```
$ awk '        {k=$1} 
       NR==FNR {a[k,++c[k]]=$0; next} 
       k in c  {for(i=1;i<=c[k];i++) 
                  print a[k,i],$2}' file1 file2

a1 c1 d1
a1 c2 d1
a2 c1 d1
a2 c2 d1
a2 c1 d2
a2 c2 d2
```